# call action from action in one controller cakephp like controller/action/action

Tags: cakephp, controller, action

i have a controller called "Movies" so the link is "localhost/Movies" and have some actions in this controller like "localhost/Movies/view/[id]" , "localhost/Movies/view/category/[id]" if i want to make a path by the category name and sub category name like "localhost/Movies/English/new" .

how can i do something like this in cakephp 2. my project now like "localhost/English/new" but i want to put Movies in this path, to make it more fixable, if i want to make a new category just add a column in my database .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand, maybe by creating a custom route for your action:

In app/config/routes.php:

> Router::connect('/movies/:category/:subcategory', array('controller'=>'movies','action' => 'index'));

And you can retrieve the value in your controller with:

> echo $this->params['category'];
>
> echo $this->params['subcategory'];

You can also read about it in the cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/945/Routes-Configuration

Comment: thanks for this answer, and i think this link will help me, really thanks ! but if u could tell me more about routes, i just want to learn from your experience, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The default routing in CakePHP is as follows:

```
mydomain/controller/action/param1/param2/param3/param4/...
```

If you want to add filter options to an action, just add optional parameters to the action.

```
function index($category = null, $subcategory = null) {
   if(isset($subcategory)){
       //will execute if you pass both arguments
   }else if(isset($category)){
       //will execute if you pass one argument
   }else{
       //will execute if you pass no arguments
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

In this case, $category is param1, and $subcategory is param2. The overloaded function can receive either 1, 2, or no arguments. If this is in, for example, the ObjectsController, all these are valid URLs:

```
localhost/objects/index/              //$category==null, $subcategory==null
localhost/objects/index/foods/        //$category=='foods', $subcategory==null
localhost/objects/index/foods/green/  //$category=='foods', $subcategory=='green'
```

This allows you to control many options in the same action.

Comment: okay i will read more about routing, but could you tell me how to use this index public function !!!